# pywinauto - access submenu from tray

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to access a submenu from a tray item.

This is how I click on a menu:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import taskbar
app = pywinauto.application.Application()
taskbar.RightClickSystemTrayIcon('App tray icon', exact=True)
app.PopupMenu.MenuItem("SomeMenuItem").ClickInput()  # Clicks an item from the app's main tray menu
```

I tried using various functions from the pywinauto menuwrapper docs, but without success.
Is it possible that these functions only work for application menus?:
https://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.controls.menuwrapper.html

Here is an example of a submenu type that I want to access:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the application process before performing any action with it. It seems missed in your code (of course, the output would be very useful to understand what's really happening). Assume the code should look like that:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import taskbar
app = pywinauto.application.Application()

# start/connect is required before any action
app.connect(path='your.exe')

taskbar.RightClickSystemTrayIcon('App tray icon', exact=True)
app.PopupMenu.MenuItem("SomeMenuItem").ClickInput()
app.PopupMenu.MenuItem("SomeMenuItem->sub-menu item").ClickInput()
```

Comment: I tried your code, but when clicking on the submenu I get this error:
`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\menuwrapper.py", line 86, in check </br>
raise MenuInaccessible
pywinauto.controls.menuwrapper.MenuInaccessible`

Comment: Probably the menu is not native (maybe WPF app?). Can you see menu item texts in `Inspect.exe`?

Comment: `Inspect.exe` can be found here (Win7 x64): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\inspect.exe`

Comment: I used Inspect.exe and here is the output when hovering over the submenu item: http://i.imgur.com/aecps5f.png
It seems that Name is the same for the MainMenu and SubMenu items

Comment: Does it show the same name in `UI Automation` mode?

Comment: Yes, it's the same

Comment: Try access by index `app.PopupMenu.MenuItem("#14->#1").ClickInput()`. If it doesn't help, I'm giving up.

Comment: One possible workaround is to send `app.PopupMenu.TypeKeys('{DOWN 13}{RIGHT}{DOWN}{ENTER}')`.

Comment: I will try you suggestion when I get back to work tomorrow morning and I will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: It's also not working accessing by index: `app.PopupMenu.MenuItem("#4 -> #1").ClickInput()` 
And also using the TypeKeys workaround. It works on the menu items but it doesn't get further to submenu items when pressing {ENTER}

Comment: OK, it looks like the menu is very non-standard. pywinauto doesn't support it. `{RIGHT}` arrow may be replaced with `{ENTER}` or doing some pause. Adding parameter `set_foreground=False` to `TypeKeys()` might also help.